What would be a good weapon to use with size changing spell
Partial setting summary
It's a mage-centric world where spells are treated as family secrets (secrecy refers specifically to chants and moves needed to cast a spell, more experienced mages can omit them which allows them to use spells more freely), rarely gained by exchange or stealing, even less often by creation. Due to this, every family has access to a limited number of specific spells; because of that, their cultures have to develop complementarily to their magical arsenal.
Condensed spell description
You cause an object you can see within range to grow larger or smaller. Range and effect of this spell are variable depending on caster's skill.  For the sake of discussion, we are only talking about caster using this spell on their weapons, changing their size up to fivefold. I'm fully aware of possibility of shrinking enemy's plate armor. Spell can be cast quickly, multiple times in a row. Square-cube law is in effect.
Specifications

Said weapons are to be used by humans, against other humans in conditions ranging from 1v1 to battlefield, no siege engines and multi-person operated weapons.
By “good weapon” I mean a weapon that is useful and usable regardless of its size, in certain ranges of course.
Size range from a butter knife to a two-handed sword and weight range from around 500g to 4000g. If you have a design that could function in a wider or narrower range of sizes and weights, please share it regardless. Although change has to be somewhat substantial. Changing knife into a slightly bigger knife is not exactly what i have in mind.
Thrown weapons, primitive firearms (up to flint/matchlocks) and explosives allowed.
Designs don't need to be perfectly realistic, if handle is a bit too thick when scaled up it doesn't matter. But if your designs would be adapted for shrinking/expanding by for example minimizing weight so that square-cube law won't make weapon useless in bigger size it would be great.
"Strange" designs working only when paired with this spell are also welcome.

My concepts so far

Stiletto with a sharpened crossguard. Obviously used as stilleto in smaller size, due to very thin handle and crossguard it seems to be prime candidate for expansion. When bigger it could work as a thrusting shortsword and maybe a pick when held by the blade, if it doesn't have edges of course.
Bludgeon of any kind. Be it warhammer, mace, maul, mallet or anything else, swing it when it's small, expand it just before impact, shrink it afterwards, rinse and repeat. Magic intensive but i like the concept.
Some shields. Especially pavise type shields would work well. Set it up, enlarge it and you have a nice, big cover. Shrink it and take it with you when you need to reposition. Center grip shields should also be fine as long as you rest their edge on the ground.
Most thrown weapons seem to be a good fit, although physics is not my strong suit. Theoretically momentum and kinetic energy should increase, but I'm well aware projectiles are more complex than that and I'm not sure how gaining additional mass would influence their flight. At the very least you could throw them straight down without concern for any of that.
Explosives seem to be pretty great when paired with this spell. Throw bomb, enlarge bomb when it lands, more explosive->bigger explosion.

TL;DR What would be a good design for a weapon that can change its size by magical means? Square-cube law in effect.

This site is to help you with your worldbuilding, not to help you power-game D&D (that's RPG.SE).  In particular, we do not work in worlds already developed by third parties, so at a minimum the 7th dot point in your Specifications must bed edited out.  We might be able to look at a question for tactics where magic similar to a D&D spell exists in your universe, but it needs to be much more tightly scoped - who/what is being fought by who/what with what technology limits.  As asked, everything from starships vs surface bases to dwarves vs giants is in scope.

Ok, i understand. Technically question is about setting im working on, but since it's based on D&D i thought it'd be more efficient to reference the basic system, than to write partial setting synopsis. I will correct that.

I strongly suggest that you post on RPG.SE instead unless of here if you want answers that incorporate the D&D rules (of which edition?) - but even there you will need to scope much more tightly who is using the magic and who/what is the target or it will get closed for being too broad.

A rock dropped from above ..
Any other missile with any horizontal movement at all can reasonably be argued by the target characters player to have it's trajectory altered by any increase in weight after being launched and fall short of the target, increased mass = increased pull of gravity = an altered and shortened trajectory .. The only way you avoid that argument between players is dropping it directly down, and you don't want that argument so don't allow a mage to use the spell on a fast moving missile, just say it's moving too fast to target .. But that aside what @KerrAvon2055 said.

Never intended this question to be about powergaming, but about development of weapons if size changing spell would be available. Used D&D as a shorthand due to it's wide and uniform recognition. Anyway, is the question better formulated now?

The square cube law is not your friend here, a sword scaled down to a butter knife would be as flimsy as tinfoil, and butter knife sized blade scaled up to a greatsword would be too heavy to lift.

Fully aware of that, that is why i asked this question.

By not your friend, I mean it makes it impossible over the size range you ask, you would need a meterial stronger than anything in real life.

As is said in the question, size and weight ranges are flexible. Butter knife - longsword range is a range that i'd like answers to operate in, not follow exactly, it can even be butter knife - dagger type size change (which is still doubling in size depending on a type of a dagger).

VTC:Too Story-Based. Any weapon can benefit from this condition. Which weapon is good/best/etc. depends entirely on narrative necessity. Per the [help/dont-ask], questions that lead to all answers having equal value are prohibited. (Also note on the same Help Center page that giving your own answers and asking for more is also prohibited.)

If zi enlarge a crossbow bolt I just fired and enlarge it to 5x it's size. Will it go with the same speed or the same energy? With the same speed it'll get a huge energy boost, impacting harder. With the same energy it'll slow down as it grows, losing it's besch characteristics of being able to penetrate.

The cubed-squared law does not directly effect the mass of an object, please clarify the weight effects of this spell. Without that clarification there is no objective best weapon, possibly with it as well I'd have to think about that.

You seem to be assuming that when the size of a moving object is changed, its density and velocity remain the same.  You can make that assumption, sure, but do be aware that it is extremely powerful.  Momentum, kinetic energy, and gravitational potential energy all scale linearly with mass, which itself scales as the cube of length (assuming constant density).  If you can instantly quintuple the size of an object in every dimension then you thereby increase its kinetic energy (for example) by a factor of 125.  "Overwhelming" doesn't really capture the combat advantage that could provide.

I would definitely go with projectiles.
Regardless how mass vs speed vs energy works in your scenario, there is almost always a benefit of suddenly enlarging your projectile before it hits the enemy. If the enlarged projectile keeps the velocity, then definitely make sure to enlarge all projectiles the second they are launched. If the Projectiles lose velocity upo the increase of mass, just enlarge them a second later, right before they hit the target and lose velocity anyway.
Lets start with the simplest:
1. Sling. stones cast from a sling were usually around the size of a thumb, which were deadly to unarmored humans, and severely painful to armored ones. 5-fold increase gives you a rock the size of a basketball. Assuming the rock retains its speed for the split second before it hits the target, it would devastate just about anyone, armor be damned, and even damage weaker fortifications.
2. Spear-throwers. If you can turn a 1meter javelin thrown from a spear-thrower/atlatl into a 5meter long pike, you just made most cavalry and heavy infantry obsolete, as there are no knights or armored troops that could survive a hit of something like that.
3. Bows and crossbows: like the spear-thrower, but vastly more dangerous. Sure, a suddenly enlarged arrow or bolt would lose a lot of its velocity due to drag, but since it was going at least a 100m/s initially, it hardly matters. The superbolt/superarrow would not just pierce your enemy, it will tear them in half.
4. Boomerangs, throwing stars, orions, and rabbit sticks. Most of these weapons would normally be pretty useless in combat, and used for hunting. But if you could enlarge your boomerang 5 times mid-flight, it would hit with enough force to cut a man in half.
All in all, projectile enlargement makes most kinds of "medieval" style warfare obsolete. Every Spellcaster is now their own siege weapon, artillery piece and a machinegunner in one. there is almost no point in having cavalry or infantry, they would just get massacred. All but the most robust fortifications become obsolete, the castles would need to be replaced by low, dug-in, early modern fortresses, like these from the Napoleonic wars. Anything standing tall would be wasted with enlarged stones easily.
Misc Options:
Castle Piercer. Shape a dagger like a thick, dull chisel. get your man next to a castle wall that seem too thick to break apart with boulders. have them ram the chisel-dagger between the wall blocks and enlarge it, to break the wall. Repeat a dozen times and the wall crumbles.
God-Whip. Usually, whips are useless in combat. Not in this scenario. Have them use a standard whip with metal weights at the end. Have them enlarge the whip 5 times in the split second as it is cracked. The tip of a whip moves at at least 900m/s, easily 3 times the speed of sound. If you turn the tip of the whip from a tiny dot into a bullet-sized ball, it will hit with twice the energy of a musket ball to devastating effect. If the user times the continuous cracking and enlarging/shrinking the whip well, they can use it as a short range semi-auto gun with endless ammo.
Supersonic Bows. There is a complex math regarding the length of the bow/crossbow lath, and its power, but increasing the bow's length pretty much always increases its draw at least proportionally, and increasing draw, even by a small factor, greatly increases power. So, if you could pull a bow or load a crossbow (preferably with an already oversized arrow, to save time) and then enlarge it 5 times before releasing the string, the force would be absurdly greater. Back of the napkin math says that a longbow enlarged 5 times would be casting its pike-sized mega-arrow at at least Mach 2. An enlargenned crossbow - Mach 6 - twice that of a bullet from a hunting rifle. Sure, both the super bows and the crossbow would be destroyed after one shot due to the forces involved, but that one shot is likely going to ruin your opponent's day.
Supersonic Torsion weapons. The thing about rope is that its tensile strength is not linear with its diameter: a rope half as thick is not half as strong, but a bit stronger. This allows you to use Shrinking Spells as weapons. Wind thick rope over something. Instantly shrink the rope. The rope, assuming it was well made, will rather uncoil that snap if possible, and then the same principle as the whip applies: the tip of the rope will move absurdly, exponentially faster than the first coil, letting you cast projectiles with ludicrous speeds, pull down enemy towers, slam their gates with "wind-up" battering rams etc. Even in personal combat, you could cast a lasso at someone, and shrink it to become an instant garrote.
Side note: the real advantage is not in using the Size Spells directly in combat, but in agriculture and industry. Being able to shrink and enlarge tools (or even weapons used as tools) would allow them to near instantly dig mines, trenches and canals, cut stone for construction, instantly chop down trees, plow land, dig wells, etc etc. The Size Spell casters can make just about every industry so much more efficient that their kingdom would win most wars through economic advantage alone. 

I don't follow the "just enlarge them later" idea. Either the projectile impacts before enlargement moving at the same velocity, or it impacts after enlargement while moving slower. There's no way to impact with both the same speed and greater mass if both change simultaneously (you can't increase the mass and then decrease speed after some delay). But who knows how any of it actually works to begin with.

I am fully aware of non-combat usefulness of this spell. That's why i didn't ask for it. Question about weapons is more complicated and because of that more interesting. But i really like your ideas. Math is a bit iffy  when it comes to enlarging moving objects of course, but with a bit of leeway I think those are some of the most fun ideas here. Especially the God-Whip.

Supersonic Bows: Every bow has an ideal arm length based on the material(s) it is made out of.   A longer bow arm adds weight which slows the bow down, and a thicker bow arm increases the tension/compression in the extremities of the bow arm making it more likely to snap.  Enlarging a bow as it shoots will either reduce its launch velocity or break it.

The OP also mentions that the caster needs to see a thing to change its size and that the spell has a limited range. Most of these things move too fast to see once in motion for this to be a reliable spell.  It also means taking your eye off the enemy to focus on your weapon which is a big no-no in every style of combat that I can think of.

Frame challenge - do not use on friendly forces, except for storage
All weapons are designed to work at the size they are.  If a sword would be "better" by being 5 cm longer then the swordsmith would make a sword 5 cm longer.  Changing the size of any weapon that friendly forces are using will make it less effective in anything resembling the real world (rather than D&D/Pathfinder etc).  The only possible exception is related to ranged weapons and depends on the physics - if a projectile will maintain its launching speed if it is resized in flight then upsizing a projectile immediately after launch will increase its momentum and kinetic energy.  However, if a projectile maintains its launching momentum if it is resized then it messes up the trajectory and decreases its kinetic energy enormously - do not use.
This leads to the obvious corollary - neutralise enemy weapons/protection by resizing them.  Making them bigger is the preferable choice - a polearm/sword/shield that suddenly increases in size is too big to wield and likely to be dropped, armour that is suddenly resized is frankly hilarious and much less messy than downsized armour and so on.  The advantage of making enemy equipment larger is that it is very likely to be abandoned on the battlefield, at which point it can be collected by the friendly side and resized for re-use or downsized for storage as loot, which leads to...
Let's look at logistics (I believe I've put the "Amateurs think tactics, professions think logistics" quote in roughly half my answers to date and it applies here too.)  Depending on how much magic exists (eg plentiful teleport portals, bags of holding, magical creation of food/water/equipment) this may be a non-issue, however, in a specialised magic setting it is critical.  Shrinking supplies, ammunition and loot gives a force with that capability a huge edge in range and/or strategic speed.
TL;DR no weapon is going to be improved by being resized, or it would be made at that size.  Resizing enemy weapons and armour will disarm them and disrupt their formations.  The ability to reduce the size of carried items lets more stuff be carried, giving greater speed and/or range.

It's true that weapons are typically designed optimally for their purpose. However, 'optimally' also includes ease of carrying, storage, and use. We don't use swords that are dozens of feet long because they would be too bulky and heavy to swing. That doesn't mean that making a sword already in motion dozens of feet long wouldn't make it more effective, especially if you could rapidly shrink it again before the weight forced you to drop it.

@PoeticallyPsychotic there might be some super-complicated, very rapid enlarge-and-shrink moves that could be used offensively, but without serious asymmetry it's likely that enlarging a sword will push the handle back out of the wielder's own grasp as the pointy end extends.  "In war, even the simplest things are difficult" - given a choice between trying to manage a fancy trick and simply enlarging the armour of every 3rd person in the enemy front rank to render the line hopelessly compromised, I'd opt for the simple plan.

Fancy tricks could be used for showing-off in duels, but I completely agree with rest of the statement. I was aware of logistics-oriented use for this spell, and that it would be way better this way. I am also aware of how humans optimize everything, so edge case uses would not be as popular. I considered it more of a "fun" question. Probbably something that bored mages came up with in their free time. Anyway i like your ideas of battlefield use, especially shrinking weapons to loot them is a fun idea, that i didn't thought of. Thank you.

The humble quarterstaff
When you can rapidly increase size by 5 (and thus weight by 125), you don't need a specialized striking end; mass alone will get the job done for you. Therefore, minimize the weight and maximize the balance of the 'base' form of the weapon.
Being able to strike with and (maybe even more importantly) hold the weapon at any point along its length will be crucial for controlling it properly, as the momentum increases by 125x or more (if it started below normal size). With a quarterstaff, you can keep the center of mass more or less stationary while still spinning it very effectively for a strike. This makes it much easier to use rapidly in combat without the weapon flying out of your hands.
The quarterstaff also lets you pull most of the tricks you would with a spear, such as bracing it on the ground and then expanding it for a sudden poke (with a whole lot of mass behind it) against a distant target, or to propel yourself in a direction if you're strong enough to hold on.
Lastly, you'll have a fairly large body of existing works to draw on for techniques, because the Monkey King's expanding staff is such an iconic weapon. For instance, the webcomic (and now anime) "God of Highschool" uses the staff Yeoui's ability to rapidly expand/contract for countless tricks, unique attacks, and stunts.
The net
For thrown weapons, the net gets much better with the ability to expand and contract. With the area it covers increasing by 25x it becomes very hard to dodge, and contracting again would cinch it tight around the target. Shrinking by 5x also makes it much more convenient to store and carry, which in turn allows you to use more durable (but heavier) materials like steel wire. A tighter weave is also probably optimal, so targets can't slip through the gaps in the expanded net.
There are probably other weapons you could invent to exploit the momentum gaining aspect of the spell (and some of the other answers are already doing so), but for existing thrown weapons, I think the net's reliance on a wide 'striking' surface makes it the most improved, and would thus have been adopted at least by the first people to invent the spell.

Thank you. I really like both of your ideas, especially technique aspect of fighting with expanding quaterstaff. Sounds fun, would probbably look cool and I can imagine it being reasonably useful.

Flechettes with poison.
Firearms, throwing out heavy darts at velocity with tips coated (or a nicely engineered piston in each projectile for delivery) the most potent poison are sure to pierce flesh. Alternatively, this would be a cupped dart with a modified load, the poison stuck there with something sticky and water/blood soluble like crystalized honey.
For the sake of making it work, I'll insist on cartridges and a weapon a bit like a large shotgun in form, single shot or if you want to push the boat out, double barreled.
Say refined botulinum toxin - 1 gram can kill 1,000,000 people. OK, so you're not going to get the pure stuff, but even at a hundredth of the pure strength, a dart set to deliver 1/2 of a gram at full size is going to deliver 1/250th of that at small size, i.e. 400 micrograms - this would still be enough to kill several thousand people.
Advantages:
~ At full size, these would have great stopping power, basically punching holes in the target.
~ At small size they could be an insignificant physical impact (barely more than a wasp sting) for a few seconds and the little "PIP!" sound of firing might easily be drowned out by ambient noise making them great for hard infiltration during taking over a base/shipment etc..
~ At both sizes, deadly.
Disadvantages.
~ Large weapon, more difficult to carry than a sidearm.
~ Lower shot rate than a revolver.
~ Takes a few seconds (maybe 5 seconds) to reload.
~ Expensive amo. especially with a plunger.
~ Slightly overkill for the purpose of peer-to-peer targets, though effective.
~ At small size shooting a big target, this would result in a delay before lethal effectiveness (30 seconds to a minute, but a shot leg could fail instantly, or at most within a handful of seconds).

The problem with most poisons is that they will almost certainly not behave the same when scaled up or down - botulinum toxin simply will not bind to the same protein receptors if it's 5x as large as normal. I guess this comes down to if the enlarging actually enlarges the matter itself, or somehow just creates more of it.

Shhh! I think I got away with it. 

Yeah, to be fair I haven't decided on it yet (enlarge vs create matter), but i really like this answer. It being overkill makes it even better. And exactly the handwaving amount i like. Thank you.

On the topic of projectiles, expanding an object mid-flight is not actually the best use of this magic if it respects conservation of momentum.
The equation for momentum is simply mass times velocity. This means that if you increase a projectile’s mass by a factor of 125 (the result of increasing its size by a factor of 5) then the velocity must also be reduced by the same factor. However, the inverse is also true: reducing a projectile’s mass will multiply its velocity accordingly. Consider this example:
An arrow has a mass of 0.02 kilograms and is shot with a velocity of 60 meters per second. Increasing its mass to 2.5kg would reduce its velocity to 0.48m/s. However, reducing its mass to 0.00016 kg would increase its velocity to 7500m/s. This is many times faster than the muzzle velocity of modern firearms. Our giant arrow is hardly moving fast enough to cause a bruise, while our tiny arrow has become a supersonic bullet that will pierce plate armor like paper.
Additional bonuses: a smaller projectile has a smaller cross sectional surface area, which reduces air resistance. It also has a smaller point of impact, which improves its effectiveness at penetrating armor.

Reduce the mass to near-zero, and relativity starts to come into effect. Momentum may be conserved, but imagine if you could toss some rocks into the air, drop their mass to arbitrarily-small scales, and watch as near-lightspeed bolts of radiation slice through mountains. (Of course they wouldn’t be able to affect mountains significantly ‘cause momentum is conserved, but you get the idea. +1)

Thank you for your answer. Informative and simple to understand. As I said, physics is not my strong suit, but your answer clarified any confusion about projectiles i had left. As for controlgroup's comment - I really like the idea. didn't even consider dropping mass so far, I think it would be a great "trick" for a powerful and experienced mage that pushed this spell to its limits.

@controlgroup would it be fast enough for relativistic nuclear stuff? https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/

@Trioxidane It would work not at all if mass is reduced as well, you'd just be throwing toothpicks instead of spears. If mass is conserved, then you concentrate the force on a smaller cross-section, so that would reduce drag and increase penetration power against inflexible targets (i.e. plate mail may be pierced better but chain mail with padding will still distribute the impact, with detail differences).

@Trioxidane You might be able to get it going that fast but you're still limited by momentum. The net effect would still be roughly the same; you can just make it impossible to dodge.

What you care about is not momentum, but energy. The damage a projectile can inflict to  a target depends on how much kinetic energy it can transfer to the target. While momentum is mv, kinetic energy is 0.5mv^2, the key point being that velocity is squared here, so if momentum is conserved you can reduce mass and increase velocity by the same amount, increasing the kinetic energy in the process. The arrow example in this post would go from 36J to 4500J of energy when shrunk in flight (divide its mass by 125 to multiply its energy by 125).

@Leo Your math is a bit off. Dividing mass by 125 multiplies velocity by 125, and that multiplier will then be squared in the kinetic energy formula. That gives a kinetic energy multiplier of 15625, which results in 562500 Joules. This is more energy than a high calibre bullet, though it’s unlikely a wooden arrow could withstand this much energy. It would certainly break apart mid air. It might be more effective to use a modest velocity multiplier of 8 (energy multiplier of 64, resulting from a half size projectile).

@chai_tea The kinetic energy formula has both velocity squared and mass, so if you divide by 125 for the mass part and multiply by 125 squared for the velocity part, you end up multiplying by 125 at the end. I think you are missing the mass division in your calculations. In the end it's still good to shrink your arrows, and you still need not to overdo it to avoid them disintegrating, only the numbers are a bit different :)

Ah you’re right, I did forget to divide the mass. I knew those numbers felt a little high, but figured that was pretty normal once you start screwing with physics.

Flamethrower
To use a flamethrower on the battlefield, a large amount of flammable material and a powerful pump are necessary. It is well known that in Eastern Roman Empire, this was achieved using siphons mounted on ships.
The size changing spell makes this easy to accomplish. Expand a container holding 1 kg of flammable material to five times its size, then shrink only the container back to one-fifth of its size. More than 100 kg of oil will shoot out from the nozzle, and by igniting it, you can burn nearby opponents. The flow rate can be adjusted by the speed of shrinking and the size of the nozzle, allowing you to control the recoil and range.

It is more of a logistics oriented answer, nonetheless it's ture. Real power of this spells lies in shrinking army's supplies. I was aware of that, but i didn't thought about flamethrower specifically. Thank you.

A makeshift 'gun' and anything spear like
There's two clear winners. First let's look at a projectile weapon.
'Gun'
Without knowing how enlarging projectiles work in the air I'll avoid that pitfall. (If enlarged, does it keep it's speed or slow down to conserve some equal energy? It becomes more difficult at range. Will enlarging projectiles work?) I'll go with a more simple design. A gun, or more specific a rifle.
From the description an enlargement or ensmallment can be done very quick. This means we can use it to propell something. A metal tube with a long rod inside. When enlarging it up to 5 time's it's size (or 25 if it was shrunk to 1/5th it's size) it can push things. As only one side of the tube is open it'll go out there. Place anything in front and it'll 'yeet' it at high speeds. The longer the rod, the higher the speed.
This can be done to create guns and cannons long before gunpowder. An army that can already 'shoot' any piece of wood, or a small or gigantic metal ball at an enemy is very powerful. (I've added a siege weapon as a bonus) It will also make the (re)loading process much simpler, as well as not requiring the incredible tight engineering you would want with gunpowder guns. Does the rod break during enlarging? Use a thicker one.
You'll have a for the time high speed reload gun with a huge lethality. Though 'no siege weapons' was called, you can smash down walls and doors as they are only made to be resistant to trebuchets and catapults.
God Gun Spears
Spears, naginata, halberd or other polearms. They fit the bill as excellent weapon in normal combat. With enlarging they become much more dangerous.
Range is a great thing. It is why spears are so powerful. With designs like the Macedonian Phalanx and other multi man spear designs we can see bigger is very effective.
Brace your long spear in the sand, aim at the enemy and enlarge. As simple as that. With temporarily 5x the size you can kill by just the blunt force alone, going very fast like the gun from before. A single person with the range of a multi-man spear. You can thrust by enlarging, shrinking it and aim again. Together with a big shield you can be untouchable for so many, requiring little skill and effort to absolutely demolish opponents at range. Just have several miniturised spear types ready to replace your current one, should the stress between the ground and an opponents face proove too much.
For some math to see how it works out: a typical spear is 180-240cm (6-8ft) and a width of 4,3-4,5cm (1,7-1,8inch). I'll just take the biggest of each. Enlarge it five times, and you'll have a spear of 12m (39ft) and 22cm (8,7inch). A Macedonian Phalanx had up to 6m, requiring part of it to be held by multiple people. 12m is a very respectable distance.
Now we start with a 12m spear we reduced to 2,4m. That means we can increase the 2,4m spear by 25. The spear becomes a 60m (197ft) long 1,12m wide behemoth. It might be less than the range of a longbow (140-300m or 450-1000ft), but it is still unbelievably long and can strike through multiple people at once.
The enlarging described seems faster than a whole second, but let us say it takes a full second to enlarge and reduce the spear. That would mean it travels 57,6m/s or 207km/h (129miles/h). This happens to be about the terminal velocity of a human. Imagine jumping out if a plane and landing on a metre wide top of a tree, which might be made of metal. That is what you do up to 60m of distance.
You can have a personal batallion of tight knit soldiers with shields, and an array of spears on special stands behind them. On command they step aside, so a 60 by 1m spear can stab through. After which the next spear does the same. It is absolutely brutal.
To make it for the specific purpose you can have a spear with a wide, horizontal bar of a metre on top. That would mean in the end a 25 metre wide bar slashing over 60m of the battlefield. With some holes in the bar where you put metal balls you can even make it 'ranged', where after 60m the balls fly out at 207km/h, making it longer ranged than a longbow.
These might even be used as siege weapons, though the stress on the metal could make it fail catastrophically, shooting metal shards at high speed in all directions.
Conclusion
Both weapons are simple. They do not fail from range issues (the magic is more difficult at range), they both use relatively simple mechanisms that can be made to be robust for long repeated use. They offer range advantages. The only real skill required is the magic, after which the aiming of the weapons is the most difficult.
Bonus - bombs
Enlarging can put stress on things. Put a rock in a metal shell. Enlarge the rock. Watch it explode.

Shrinking a spear is just as useful as enlarging it.  The biggest downfall of pikes is that once and enemy gets past the pointy bit, it is useless, the Roman and Zulu Empires were built on the realization that a short spear that can angle around a shield is better if you have big enough of a shield yourself to push through a pike wall safely or if the terrain makes a phalanx unmanageable.  This spell means you can choose when a pike or a short spear is preferred depending on how the battle is going.

I really like the "piston" gun idea. It being a possible siege weapon is not a problem. Whole question is about scaling things up and down so it is a logical conclusion. Size-changing spears and similiar weapons were already mentioned but i appreciate your answer anyway. Thank you.

@4dam I added the spears as they are absolute units. I've added some calculations for super spears, which you might alter with a trident or just a horizontal metal bar for extra effectiveness. A 60+m long 207km/h piece of metal  killing anyone in its path. Add some metal balls on top to 'fire' them if you want.

@Nosajimiki He's suggesting a short-spear phalanx that enlarges spears just to stab attackers, long before they can get into close combat range. The stabbing also goes right through any shield at 200 km/h.

@toolforger to be fair, I've added the calculations later. I can imagine it was hard to see the full extend (pun intended) of the spears at a cursory read before that point.

A suggestion as a frame challenge: Gold
Or whatever your society deems as valuable
Money buys power. The power to raise armies, to build siege weapons, to bribe competitors. If your mage can make something bigger, then he would find a gold coin and multiply it.
This has an additional benefit of keeping your spell secret. You don't need to tell anyone where the money came from. In contrast, the absolute moment you turn a dagger into a lance, the secret is out.
If you insist in using the spell in the battlefield, your best bet is a standard long bow. You could instantly turn your legion of archers into a legion of ballistas by modifying the arrow size before impact.

Gold multiplication will lead to inflation. If a state does this, it's almost useless since it won't expand the production capacities; if a family does this, it will devalue gold more slowly, but greed and need will make them create more gold than the economy reachable by trade routes can deliver value for, so again they'll find that gold alone does not solve all their problems, but their neighbours will want to capture their mages and make gold themselves.

@toolforger yes, but the point I was trying to make is that this cast of mages would be infinitely wealthy. They can create matter. You could feed your troops with a loaf if bread, you could turn a mug of beer into a brewery. Why would they risk battle when they could subvert other cultures by their sheer resources?

Then the answer uses the wrong example. Bread, Wood, Stone would be better ones, as these have intrinsic value that gold does not. If you can create matter, gold will buy you much less than you seem to think. -- I also think that the frame challenge is already answered: He's well aware of nonmilitary uses of such a spell, knows how to do worldbuilding with or around that, and was specifically asking about physics-related uses.

@toolforger I did qualify the answer with Or whatever your society deems as valuable. And I think you are both missing the point. Battle is an incredibly risky endeavor. It is only a last resort. Rather, these mages would be bankers and royalty because of their power. Their armies would be the best fed and best supplied in the land. You would never find a mage on the battlefield risking their neck to enhance weapon effectiveness. The frame challenge implies that the question is moot. The situation would never happen.

Still, he's asking about the weapons aspect, stating (repeatedly) that the other aspects are already accounted for. I find it a bit improper to insist on challenging exactly the aspect that he has clearly stated as "that's what I want to know", but each to his own.

Castles & Siege Works
The single most influential battlefield advantages in Ancient and Medieval style warfare is not one weapon or another.  They were fortifications and siegeworks.  A few dozen guys in a castle could resist a whole army. Or inversely, an army with a siege tower could storm an otherwise unbeatable castle. The problem in both of these cases is that they take a long time to build, and they were too big to march with.  So, if you needed to go on the defense quickly, you were typically limited to maybe a basic palisade fort or something that could be quickly and easily thrown together, and if you wanted to attack a proper castle, then you'd need to spend months or even years building large siege works capable of overcoming the defenses.
Now image if your army hads a wagon full of modular fortifications and siege works already built.  Now instead of needing to siege a castle and risk a reinforcing army showing up, you can just enlarge some tiny siege towers, pontoon bridges, and whatever else you need to get your men into the enemy castle directly, that very day. Depending on how the spell works you may even be able to simple shrink a small section of a castle's wall either creating a doorway or simply collapsing it.  Or the inverse happens, your scouts notice an enemy army closing in on you; so, you spring up a castle depriving the enemy of a fair fight on an open battlefield.
Also, as others have pointed out, we don't know if momentum is persevered when you grow a missle weapon, but we do know that gravity is.  If your men are atop a 30ft wall throwing rocks down at the enemy, being able to turn those rocks into boulders will increase their lethality by a lot.
Early access to Advanced Firearms
The first firearms in Europe were introduced in the 1300s.  However, the tools required for precision gunmaking did not yet exist. If gunmakers could build a gun, grow it so that they could measure and shape things more precisely, then shrink it down again, then they would be able to do by hand what we could not achieve until the 1700s making things like revolver chambers and rifled barrels able to be made before the invention of the machines that allowed the needed level of precision.
Cheaper/More resources
Metal armor was mostly only worn by the nobility and mercenaries, but a significant part of the cost of armor was the steel.  If you could simply grow an ingot of steel, cut a piece off, and grow it back, then this expensive resource suddenly becomes very cheap.  Not only does this open up better access to metal armor for peasants (like brigandine or lorica), but it also opens up a lot of the path towards industrialization which would help support the economy of a stronger army.
Frankly, there are many resources and logistics that you could improve efficiency with this way.  Like you could shrink your rations so that you can improve your army's operational range and reduce how many wagons you need.  You could shrink your tents, mess, etc. so your men can march less encumbered which further increases your operational range and allows your army to be more mobile.  A soldier could also carry more encampment tools like a shovel, an axe, a machete, etc. allowing them more options and ease for camp site preparation.
You could also in theory also grow precious metals like silver or gold to purchase foreign goods. Your own people would quickly stop using material weights as a basis for currency, because they will know about enlarging; so, your own people might need to resort to paper money.  But, if you are a foreign army in foreign lands, then you will have all sorts of options to pay for spies and mercenaries from among the local populous and to bribe local lords and allied kings into keeping the lands from forming a united coalition against you.
Variable Pikes
In the rare case you are forced to fight on the battlefield, the most useful common fantasy weapon to be able to grow and shrink will be the pike/spear.  Most weapons already are their ideal weight and size.  Any bigger or smaller and they become to unwieldy or loose too much lethality, but spears and pikes are a bit different. In a head to head battle, no ancient or medieval weapon could outperform the pike, but it had one major drawback.  Its usefulness only goes up in a fantasy setting where the added reach will be your best bet when facing giant monsters, and their skin may be too thick to pierce with arrows.
But, in a forest or uneven terrain, the short spear is the king of the battle field.  It strikes faster and more precisely than weapons that need to be swung while being short enough that you do not get locked into a ridged formation.  And it can be thrusted around shields and into gaps in armor more readily than a pike.
Lastly, if you are in a phalanx or pike block, and an enemy gets past the first few spears, you can adapt your spear to be short enough to keep him in your kill range.
Why not change a weapon's size in flight or as it is swung
A lot of suggestions involve firing an object and then growing it, but the OP stipulates "You cause an object you can see within range to grow larger or smaller."  Once you throw or fire an object, chances are you will not be able to fix your eyes on it until it is far enough away that its angular velocity is low enough to track; so, you either can not see the missile or it is too far away making casting the spell somewhere between very hard and impossible.  A few of your most proficient mages might be able to fire an arrow and turn it into a spear, but this would be a "trick shot" that I can't imagine you'd be able to make wide-scale use of.
Even worse would be trying to enlarge your weapon in melee.  The absolute worst thing you can do in a melee is take your eyes off the enemy.  It is a common mistake for amature martial artists to let their focus slip from what the opponent is doing to what they are doing.  Yes you can enlarge your mace mid-swing making it impossible to block, but in that moment you are no longer watching your opponent, but he is watching you.  This means he can predict your next movement, but you can not predict his making it trival for him to side-step your attack and land his next attack in your most vulnerable spot.  It also means you can not redirect your attack.  HEMA is full of techniques that involve feinting and redirecting your weapon mid-swing.  If you enlarge your weapon mid-swing, you will be forced to over-commit to the attack leaving you vulnerable even if you manage to caste the spell without breaking focus.
That said, an archer could carry a lot more arrows if he shrinks them first.

It's not exactly an answer for my question, but I really like the idea of modular "inflatable" fortifications. A lot of mages would be needed to build them efficiently, but i can see it being useful. Thank you.

@4dam I've expanded on my answer to try to include more specifically what you asked about, but there are frankly a lot of unintended consequences to a spell like this that allow an army to be far more effective than simply being able to change the size of their weapons in battle.

I'm not sure if this works better as a full answer or in some other discussion format, but I've realized something with potentially big implications about this power, and it's too long for a comment.
The power breaks conservation of momentum no matter what. Several answers and comments have assumed that to maintain conservation of momentum, the objects would have to slow down upon being expanded and speed up upon being shrunk.
However, that only upholds conservation of momentum from one perspective, and momentum only exists relative to a perspective.
An example. A spellcaster is in a room with a rock. He casts expand on the rock. It remains stationary, right?
What if that room is actually the inside of a train car? The 'stationary' rock is now moving in the same direction as the train; when you cast expand on it, does it now suddenly throw on the brakes, rolling along the room's floor towards the back of the train? Nothing pushed it, so where is the force coming from?
Back to the 'stationary' room, what about the movement and rotation of the planet? Does the rock suddenly fly in some direction to maintain its momentum relative to the Sun? To the core of the galaxy?
There is no "true" stationary perspective. No matter what, casting this spell screws up momentum from some perspective. All perspectives except of one, in fact.
Implications
The spell must define a stationary perspective, the one frame of reference from which the object maintains its momentum from before. Probably, by default, this is the objects center of mass, the caster's center of mass, or the planet's center of mass.
But clever casters can do a whole lot with any of those, exploiting the fact that from the other two perspectives, the spell is 'cheating' momentum.
Melee weapons can change direction and speed mid-swing. Ranged weapons can significantly change their trajectory. These tricks get much more potent if the caster can move rapidly on their own, via spells, horses, what-have you. For instance, if the reference point is the earth, and you carry a rock while walking towards an enemy... you can let go of the rock and cast the spell, and the rock will accelerate to 125x your walking speed, shooting out of your hands and striking the enemy. It won't have any more momentum than if you'd bumped into the target... but now imagine you were riding on a galloping horse when you cast the spell, and the small rock was a bowling ball. That person is falling down, and they might not be getting up again.
But if a skilled caster could probably set the frame of reference however they wanted, things get even more interesting. Going back to the last example, now you don't need to move yourself, you just cast the spell and set the reference as a point extremely fast behind you, and the rock shoots forward when you shrink it. Better yet, do the opposite, and send an enlarged rock hurtling towards a reference point moving rapidly in the direction you are facing.
A weapon/tool every master of this spell would want
...is a weighted harness to control their own momentum. By expanding the weights, and with the harness to distribute the force across their body, a master could pull themself around the battlefield. Probably nothing too drastic (not without breaking their own neck, anyway), but they could jerk out of the way of incoming attacks, jerk back into range for a counterattack, and then hit the deck, all in seconds. They'd be able to move in had-to-predict jerks, and by targeting the weights on specific parts of their body, could also apply the same principle to individual limbs and movements.
This is not nearly as useful as the expanding weapons suggested by other users (myself included)... for mass combat. In a mage duel, against an opponent with tricks to rival your own (or even this spell as well), this is what would give a master the edge over their opponent.

Forget all weapons!
Armor
Your spell is completely and utterly overpowered.
Shrink your enemies armor (first target: helmet), clothing, weapons. Even if they survive the shrinking (questionable), they are now unarmed and naked.
Works in full range, requires no weapons of your own. Completely removes any threat from anyone if cast quickly enough.

I'm not sure I completely understand the limitations. So. Correct me if I'm wrong. I'll still try to do my best.
Brutally realistic solution is carpet bombing using...rocks.
Just think about it. If you drop a rock on someone from the first level of a building, it would hurt. But if you drop it from the 10the level? Yeah. That's gg. Remember. Gravity is a real killer.
Since you mentioned thrown stuff and even explosives are allowed. So. Here is how we can design our weapon.
You build a rock hurler. Whatever works best for you. Then you gather small rocks. Anything fist sized would do. Then however your magic works. Those rocks get marked. Maybe the wizard has to look at them, maybe you mark them with a special paint or liquid, maybe you put them in a bucket. Whatever.
Then they are launched at the enemy. Of course you either have a spotter or you can just calculate it. You can even have magic seeing eyes or maybe a creature or whatever.
Now once they are above your target. Your wizard uses his magic and makes the falling rocks bigger, much much bigger. Just increase the mass. You don't have to make it gigantic, I mean why not if you can. Football size or larger would be more than fine. As it falls. It will cracks skulls. An even fully armored knights won't be liking it very much. Even if once you increase they stop moving and just start falling. That's good enough. Again. Gravity will do the rest.
Congrats. You just used magic in a very realistic and boring way. And you probably decimated any large enemy foolish enough to try to attack you.
This also works perfect in sieges. Your enemies are already surrounding you. Target rich environment and all that. I mean the exact principle was used in actual sieges. Unlike what many movies show you. Oil was expensive and scarce, same with arrows. They would just throw rocks at the attackers. Like how they showed it during the battle of Helms Deeps.
What not to increase?
Melee weapon. Long story short. Actual melee weapon sizes are perfect for their purpose. Making them bigger won't help you. If anything it would be worse.
By making any weapon bigger you do get more mass and more force. Sure. But you tire more easily. Remember. Your weapon is bigger, but your human using it is still the same. Exhaustion is a real thing.
Big stuff existed. Sure. But look at the actual head sizes of great axes. Look at the size of actual war hammers. At halberds and spears. Nothing like movies and video games. You don't need a bigger weapon. It's a bad idea.
Sand?
Now if your wizard can use sand then I think this can be real op. Just mark a lot of sand. Blow it in the face of your opponent or their general direction. Increase the size and viola. Absolutely brutal.
Obviously doing it on a larger scale would be even better.
Even if they have armor. Sand will just find its way into the armor.
Needles?
Throw small needles at the enemy then increase the size. Not unlike the first option.
This can be done using Roman scorpions like machines. Then once the bundles of needles are released. Just increase the size and watch them skewer rows of enemies.
Same with a sort of pistol or weapon like launcher. I supposes this would be useful in more 1 on 1 battles. But if I was a wizard with those powers. I'm not getting to close to any enemy or accepting any challenges. Let heroes do their thing.
Reality
Basically I just tend to think of magic in a world like mechanics in a video games. How best to exploit it to get the most desired outcome. People did this in reality. We used disease and Greek fire and explosives and airplanes and buying people to open the gates and poisoning the water and everything. But, again, hope I Was not providing ideas that won't work in your world. Though you can adapt them however you like

Thank you. I really like idea about the needles. I am fully aware of weapon size limitations, that's why it was a main point of the question. I considered it a really interesting design challenge, although i could be a bit too optimistic about concept due to liking it.

Melee weapons
Others have already mentioned that this is more or less useless on traditional melee weapons for offensive usage.
However, you can create an assassin group on this spell. Just have a tiny needle, stick it into someone, expand it, watch the head (or whatever) explode. Not really all that useful in melee, since you need to get close, but absolutely devastating and easy to hide otherwise.
Ranged weapons
The obvious question already posed by others is whether momentum, speed, or kinetic energy is maintained by this. If the speed is maintained the obvious applies (as already covered), however if momentum or kinetic energy is preserved this can still be used to create devastating effects, just not necessarily by direct hits.

Build a wall wherever on the battlefield simply by throwing a rock and then enlarging it (or by just enlarging an existent rock, depends on the terrain). This can be used to cutoff small groups of the enemy forces to corner them, disrupt reinforcements, or similar effects. Basically you have permanent high ground wherever you fight.

Crush your opponent with a boulder. Shrink a large stone to a fifth of its size, throw/shoot it above your opponent, then enlarge it while it's still in mid air. It'll look like a miss for the opponent, but changing its size will change its trajectory so that it can burrow anything beneath it. Can even be used as a makeshift siege weapon, just crush the houses in that city. Even if your projectile looses speed due to the enlargement it'll have its altitude to regain speed.


Traps
Rig the battlefield with small spikes, when enemy troops are above them enlarge the spikes, depending on the growth rate this can be used to impale their troops.
1v1 Duel
If your enemy somehow has the ability to shield themself and their gear from others magical influence you can still make them stumble by enlarging that pebble beneath their foot. If timed well this can turn the tides.

I like the assassination idea, it would be useful to hurt someone who doesn't wear armor, or anything else durable enough to hurt them when shrunk. Spike trap also sounds interesting. Thank you.
